# How to check if 2 values inside a string in a list are not the same

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Super easy question. Let´s say I have this list in Python:

```
variables = ['A1,A1','A2,B2','A1,C2','B3,B3','C4,C4']
```

Now, I only need to keep those items where the value before and after the comma differs. In this case, the output would be:

```
result = ['A2,B2','A1,C2']
```

I already have a '*not-so-elegant*' solution for this:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(variables)):
    j = variables[i].split(",")
    if j[0] != j[1].replace(" ", ""):
        z = "{},{}".format(j[0], j[1])
        new_list.append(z)
```

*note: I had to add `replace` to remove whitespaces, but it´s not important...*

Is there another (**better**) way to do this? Maybe *regex*?

*note II: I also tried using a list comprehension:*

```
lista_differents = ["{},{}".format(j[0], j[1]) for i in range(len(variables)) if j[0] != j[1].replace(" ", "")]
```

But I still have to figure out how to add the line `j = variables[i].split(",")`

Any ideas?

Comment: `print([var for var in variables if str.__eq__(*var.split(","))])`

Comment: @PaulM. - Nice.  Minor correction, I think you meant to use `__ne__`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this with list comprehension and `set`. You basically split the string into 2 lists and then see if the set of those 2 elements has a len > 1 which means both are unique.

```
variables = ['A1,A1','A2,B2','A1,C2','B3,B3','C4,C4']

[i for i in variables if len(set(i.split(',')))>1]
```

```
['A2,B2', 'A1,C2']
```

If you are bothered about runtime then try this approach without a `split(',')`. This is much much faster than the fastest one in benchmark.

```
[i for i in variables if len(set(i))>3]
```

---

EDIT: Adding benchmarking results (300000 length input array, macbook pro 13)

- *Akshay Sehgal (first)* - 215 ms ± 9.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- *Akshay Sehgal (second)* - 136 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- *Aviv Yaniv* - 468 ms ± 39.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- *jakub* - 252 ms ± 29.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- *Md. Ashraful Alam* - 252 ms ± 29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach which looks at the number of **unique characters**. Max allowed is 3 (i.e. letter, number, comma).

```
l = ['A1,A1','A2,B2','A1,C2','B3,B3','C4,C4'

[i for i in l if len(set(i)) > 3]
```

#### Output:

```
['A2,B2', 'A1,C2']
```

... and a friendly challenge to @ AkshaySehgal benchmarking.  :-)

Comment: Ah thanks, I already added that solution into my answer

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - Nice one mate.  GMTA.

Answer (score 1):

```
variables = ['A1,A1','A2,B2','A1,C2','B3,B3','C4,C4']

result = [a for a in variables if a.split(',')[0]!=a.split(',')[1].replace(" ", "")]

print(result)
```

Comment: result = [v for v in variables if v.split(',')[0]!=v.split(',')[1].replace(" ", "")]. Thank you Md. Ashraful Alam!!

Answer (score 1):

```
[v for v in variables if str.__ne__(*v.replace(" ", "").split(","))]
```

You can use the `str.__ne__(x1, x2)` function, which is equivalent to `x1 != x2`. The `*` unpacks the list into separate arguments, so the outputs of `.split(",")` are made into two positional arguments (assuming there is only one `,` character in the string).

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using additional memory:

```
variables = ['A1,A1','A2,B2','A1,C2','B3,B3','C4,C4']

def find_same_with_seperator(variables, SEPERATOR = ','):
    same_vars = []
    for v in variables:
        # Finding seperator index
        seperator_index = 0
        for i in range(len(v)):
            if SEPERATOR == v[i]:
                break
            seperator_index += 1
        # If no seperator
        if 0 == seperator_index:
            continue
        # Comparing parts
        before_seperator = 0
        after_seperator  = seperator_index + 1
        the_same = True
        while after_seperator < len(v):
            if v[before_seperator] != v[after_seperator]:
                the_same = False
                break
            before_seperator += 1
            after_seperator  += 1
        if the_same:
            same_vars.append(v)
    return same_vars

# ['A1,A1', 'B3,B3', 'C4,C4']
print(find_same_with_seperator(variables))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a time-honored tradition in Python to detect if items are different by putting them into a set and counting the number of elements.

```
[a for a in variables 
   if len(set(a.split(','))) > 1]
```

Another idiom in Python is to do "assignment" inside a list comprehension by iterating over a list with only one element.  So another possible solution is:

```
[a for a in variables 
   for pair in [a.split(',')] 
   if pair[0] != pair[1]]
```

Python 3.8's [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) lets you write:

```
[a for a in variables 
   if (pair := a.split(','))[0] != pair[1]]
```

but I think that's rather ugly and hard to read.

Comment: I agree that it is harder to read, but nice use of the walrus operator.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

Answer (score 1):

This is just a classic problem. One suggested solution is checking on non-trivial rotation of the string. I believe this question has been used in several job interviews.

```
[x for x in variables if (x+','+x).find(x, 1, -1) == -1]

Out[183]: ['A2,B2', 'A1,C2']
```

---

**P/s**: This question is more about logic/algorithm than pandas or any specific programming language.